# Tinted Images with Multiple Backgrounds with a hex value

Tags: css, image, hex

http://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/

I'm looking to do something like this but with a hex value. I'm basically creating a CMS where the user can change the color of elements with a colorpicker which returns a hex value.

Is it only possible to get a color layer on an image with rgba? Or can I do it with a hex value

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is only possible using `RGBA` the way css-tricks is showing you because `HEX` values do not support transparency. What you can do though, depending on your color picker setup, is "translate" the HEX values to RGB values, then simply apply the opacity... Viewing the source of [this page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm) you can see how it is done via Javascript.

The other option, if you *have* to use HEX is to use two div elements, one with the image and another with the color. then you can set the `opacity` property on the color div without it affecting the image.
See this fiddle for how to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/Wc5Hc/